# How to save to 2 tables of a database at the same time using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-4

Hi I have a problem saving 2 tables of my database at the same time but my first table saves without a problem alone. The second table is related to the first table and has FK already. Please help..here is my code. Thanks

```
        //Save to Database
        //1st Table
        casecrawlerdbEntities1 db = new casecrawlerdbEntities1();
        document document = new document();
        document.DocumentNo = DocumentNo;
        document.Description = Description;
        document.Author = Author;
        document.PublishedDate = DateTime.Parse(PublishedDate); ;
        document.Summary = Summary;
        document.SearchKeys = richTextBox9.ToString();
        document.References = url;
        document.IsPublic = false;
        document.IsPublished = false;
        document.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.documents.AddObject(document);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //2nd Table
        content content = new content();
        content.ContentType = ContentType;
        content.Content = Content;
        db.contents.AddObject(content);
        db.SaveChanges();

        MessageBox.Show("Saved to Database");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `db.contents.AddObject(content);`, do:

```
content.Document = document;
```

(assuming that this is how the relation to the Document is named).

Also, you may try calling `db.SaveChanges();` only once (after the contents is created).